# How to get/read the cleanest url into Meta Canonical via PHP?

Tags: php, http, url, meta, canonical-link

Given: old ugly urls like `/somepage?ln=en` are rewritten in htaccess to `/en/somepage`
Given: used canonical meta tag, with this php script above it to fill in the tidy url:

How to make them like the canonical?

```
      <link rel="canonical" href="<?=$canonicalURL?>">
```

What ways can one parse the current url without any strings, or, delete the extra strings from the url and put it into the canonical url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you just want to get rid of the query string from $extensions, correct?

```
<?php
$qsIndex = strpos($extensions, '?');
$extensions = $qsIndex !== FALSE ? substr($extensions, 0, $qsIndex) : $extensions;
```

Comment: Flawless implementation, Simshaun! this clue brightened everything up.

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = parse_url('http://example.com/path/page?param=value');

print_r($url)

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /path/page
    [query] => param=value
)
```

Then you could just do:

```
$url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path']
```

Or even:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/path/page?param=value'; 
'http://example.com' . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)
```